# Downloaded projects are not imported to Android Studio shows SDK path error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[image]Hello Friends i am new to Android Studio and i would like to import an downloaded project to my Android studio but it is showing some path error and i am unable to solve that.If change the SDK path is there any problem with previous existing projects. Any one please tell me the use of the SDK path in Android Studio and please tell me how to import downloaded projects to studio...

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: hai broo the error image is added abovee... I am new to studio help mee

Comment: What happens when you press ok?

Comment: a long process takes place but the path is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Android SDK path, go to

1. File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location
2. SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +,
   add another sdk)

To change SDK from the quick start window,

1. Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure.
2. On the left under Platform Settings choose SDKs.
3. Then to the right of that choose the current android platform.
4. Delete it.
5. Add a new android platform and point it your current SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file and click invalidate caches your problem will be resolved.

Comment: This is not related to the problem formulated in the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34645248)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).